# DEBUG - Code coverage will not be imported for the following file outside of SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am running Sonar for C# projects. I am using Xunit for unit test and Dot cover is for code coverage. 
When I run sonar with dotcover coverage report I am getting this error:

> DEBUG - Code coverage will not be imported for the following file 
>   outside of SonarQube

Because of this Sonar dashboard is not showing any code coverage report.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the official documentation on how to use dotCover with the SonarQube C# Plugin and the MSBuild SonarQube Runner:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Code+Coverage+Results+Import

Following these exact steps should work. Note that you cannot collect code coverage from one machine and then re-use that same report from another machine from which the SonarQube analysis is executed: The absolute paths in the coverage report **must** exactly match with the files SonarQube analyzes.

Comment: Below is the paths of my csproj file and dotcover.html file.                                                                                                 csproj: E:/Code/TestProject/TestProjects.csproj                                                               docover: E:/Code/TestProject/dotcover.html        So both are in same machine and same folder.